# Can there be two concurrent CI runs through SCM changes?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I've configured Jenkins with Poll SCM enabled and it is scheduled

```
*/15 * * * *
```

Suppose, the job was triggered due to one SCM change.
And while this job was already running, another SCM change happens.

Will this trigger the CI immediately or will it wait for the existing run to complete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jenkins does not (in its default configuration) run concurrent builds of the same job. In your case the second SCM change will add a job to the build queue, but not execute it until the existing run is complete.

You can enable concurrent builds for a job by enabling *Execute concurrent builds if necessary* in the job configuration.